# Inserting PHP variable as param in an href link

Tags: php, html

I am using the following line inside my PHP code:

```
echo"<td><a href='EditAdminRestaurantes.php?id=1' data-ajax='false'><img src='editicon.png' width='31' height='31'></a> </td>";
```

When the PHP file is called at the browser, the resulting URL is:

```
http://../EditAdminRestaurantes.php?id=1
```

What I a need is to change the value after the ?id= param, I need to put there the PHP variable `$row[0], but when I insert the code for that, then the URL is not the expected.

This is my code for that:

```
 echo"<td><a href='EditAdminRestaurantes.php?id='".$row[0]." data-ajax='false'><img src='editicon.png' width='31' height='31'></a> </td>";
```

And the resulting URL is:

```
http://../EditAdminRestaurantes.php?id=
```

Any help is welcome.`

Comment: `echo $row[0];` what does it show?

Comment: @Harikrishnan, it shows 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You close the href attribute with a single quote before $row[0]. It needs to be closed after, like so:

```
echo"<td><a href='EditAdminRestaurantes.php?id=".$row[0]."' data-ajax='false'><img src='editicon.png' width='31' height='31'></a> </td>";
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in the quotes. If you do it this way, it will work.

```
echo '<td><a href="EditAdminRestaurantes.php?id='.$row[0].'" data-ajax="false"><img src="editicon.png" width="31" height="31"></a> </td>';
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you may need to move your single quote from before the variable to after it like so

```
echo"<td><a href='EditAdminRestaurantes.php?id=".$row[0]."' data-ajax='false'><img src='editicon.png' width='31' height='31'></a> </td>";
```